# Is the 000-default.conf virtual host file global?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I just need to clear up some confusion with the 000-default.conf file. I was following a tutorial and when it started talking about the default virtual hosts file, it only mentioned "default" and not 000-default.conf", I guess that is the new name for the default virtual hosts file?

Anyway, I just want to ask if the 000-default.conf file is used as a global virtual hosts file, so if I set in there to not list directories or turn off version info for example, will this be applied to all other virtual hosts?

And should I be doing this or is that bad practice, what is the main purpose for 000-default.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file named `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` is not special from the perspective of any settings.  The file is simply named that way so that it will be included first in your configuration.  You often want one of your virtual hosts to be used first so it is the default, if someone connects to your server by IP, or with a name that isn't covered by other virtual hosts, that 'default' virtual host will be placed in that default configuration file.

You see this `000-default.conf` commonly on systems which also have a folder named `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/` usually that is the best place to put configuration fragments that will set defaults and outside of a `<VirtualHost ..>` block.  But like I said, that isn't required, and the file names aren't really special.  You could if you were so inclined  put all your config in the `000-default.conf` if you wanted, and let it grow to become a large  ugly difficult to maintain file.

If you look at the main apache configuration, the comments where the fragment directories are included should give you hint about how the maintainers expect you to use these folders.

```
# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: What would I need to do in order to make a global virtual host config?

Comment: @Buckket5 There is no such thing as global virtualhost, that's server config, just answered in your other question.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what you mean by global?  You can store config in a file and include that in a vhost.

Comment: I meant in terms of setting default options, which was answered in my other question where I just used apache2.conf.